Calling javascript function in .cshtml file
I am calling a Javascript function which is in a .js file from a .cshtml file as in
.js file code:
var LoginForm = document.getElementById("LoginForm");
var RegForm = document.getElementById("RegForm");
var Indicator = document.getElementById("Indicator");
function register()
{
    RegForm.style.transform = "translateX("+(0)+"px)";
    LoginForm.style.transform = "translateX("+(0)+"px)";
    Indicator.style.transform = "translateX("+(100)+"px)";
}
function login()
{
    RegForm.style.transform = "translateX("+(300)+"px)";
    LoginForm.style.transform = "translateX("+(300)+"px)";
    Indicator.style.transform = "translateX("+(0)+"px)";
}


.cshtml file code :
<div class="form-container" >
     <div class="form-btn">
         <span onclick="login()">Login</span>
         <span onclick="register()">Register</span>
         <hr id="Indicator">
     </div>
     <form id="LoginForm">
         <input type="text" placeholder="Username">
         <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
         <button type="submit" class="btn">Login</button>
         <a>forgot password</a>
     </form>
     <form id="RegForm">
         <input type="text" placeholder="Username">
         <input type="email" placeholder="Email">
         <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
         <button type="submit" class="btn">Register</button>
     </form>
 </div>


So here basically when we click on login or register the forms should slide but it is not working.
What can be done?

Where does the problem lie? What debugging have you done? Are the methods being called? Are the styles being applied? Why isn't this information in the question?!

include your js file in your .cshtml file using script tag below .cshtml file code

@John I would hope OP has already done that, but good point.

@ProgrammingLlama just in case he had created a new file .js. I think he should give more infomation about the probem or the project he is doing .

To facilitate your testing, I put all the CSS/JS related codes in the same file. Maybe there are bugs in my sample code, but it does work, and I hope it will inspire you.
Test Result


Test Code
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div class="form-container no-transition">
    <div class="form-btn">
        <span id="loginTab" onclick="login()">Login</span>
        <span id="registerTab" onclick="register()">Register</span>
        <hr id="Indicator">
    </div>
    <form id="LoginForm">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username">
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Login</button>
        <a href="#">Forgot password?</a>
    </form>
    <form id="RegForm">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username">
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email">
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Register</button>
    </form>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            var LoginForm = document.getElementById("LoginForm");
            var RegForm = document.getElementById("RegForm");
            var Indicator = document.getElementById("Indicator");
            var loginTab = document.getElementById("loginTab");
            var registerTab = document.getElementById("registerTab");
            var formContainer = document.querySelector(".form-container");

            function register() {
                RegForm.style.transform = "translateX(0px)";
                LoginForm.style.transform = "translateX(300px)";
                Indicator.style.transform = "translateX(100px)";
                registerTab.classList.add("active");
                loginTab.classList.remove("active");
            }

            function login() {
                RegForm.style.transform = "translateX(300px)";
                LoginForm.style.transform = "translateX(0px)";
                Indicator.style.transform = "translateX(0px)";
                loginTab.classList.add("active");
                registerTab.classList.remove("active");
            }

            RegForm.style.transform = "translateX(300px)";
            login();

            setTimeout(function () {
                formContainer.classList.remove("no-transition");
            }, 0);

            window.register = register;
            window.login = login;
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        .form-container {
            position: relative;
            width: 300px;
            height: 400px;
            overflow: hidden;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            padding: 20px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            background-color: #fff;
        }

            .form-container.no-transition form,
            .form-container.no-transition #Indicator {
                transition: none;
            }

        .form-btn {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            position: relative;
        }

            .form-btn span {
                cursor: pointer;
                padding: 10px;
                transition: color 0.3s ease;
            }

                .form-btn span.active {
                    color: #007bff; 
                }

        form {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
            top: 60px;
        }

        #Indicator {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100px;
            height: 2px;
            background-color: #007bff; 
            transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
            top: 50px;
        }

        input[type="text"],
        input[type="password"],
        input[type="email"] {
            width: 86%;
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 8px 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        .btn {
            display: block;
            width: 86%;
            margin-top: 10px;
            padding: 10px;
            background-color: #007bff;
            color: #fff;
            border: none;
            cursor: pointer;
            transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
        }

            .btn:hover {
                background-color: #0056b3;
            }

        a {
            display: block;
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-right: 40px;
            text-align: right;
            color: #007bff;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

            a:hover {
                text-decoration: underline;
            }
    </style>
}

